# How do I perform various loop operations on the Selenium IDE web extension tool?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have it downloaded both on firefox and chrome but I am not able to perform any loop operations.

Comment: Selenium IDE is deprecated. which one are you using?

Comment: You can't perform logical loop operation in ide